# ShareActionProvider with a split ActionBar

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, shareactionprovider

I'm using a `ShareActionProvider` and would like to take advantage of the split ActionBar when there isn't enough room for it at the top -  `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`.

The action works fine when the ActionBar does not need to split:

[image: landscape]

However when the ActionBar does need to split, the ActionProvider seems to break the lower ActionBar layout completely. It fills the entire viewport below the top ActionBar and the action itself does not appear:

[image: portrait]

Has anyone been able to use these two features together successfully?

Comment: Platform bug report filed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26027

Comment: I stared issue for you.  Same issue here.  I get the same error using latest available as of this comment.  Appcompat actionbar.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the dev branch of ActionBarSherlock- https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/505

You could try that instead.

UPDATE: Now fixed in ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Some how creating a share history file fixes this issue

this can be fixed by using a custom share history file on app install.

e.g. call CreateShareHisotryFile() on App Create()

```
public class YourBrokenAPP extends Application {

  public static SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME = "c_share_hist.xml";

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();  
     CreateShareHisotryFile(); 
 }

 private void CreateShareHisotryFile() {

    String data = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?> "+
                 "<historical-records>" +
                  "<historical-record activity=\"com.google.android.apps.plus/com.google.android.libraries.social.gateway.GatewayActivity\" time=\"1426500217970\" weight=\"1.0\" />"+
            "</historical-records>";
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new     OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
         outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

then in the fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu use share history file we just created ....

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

  // Set up ShareActionProvider's default share intent
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
           MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(c_share_hist.xml);
}
```

Note that historical-records needs @ least one historical-record child element in the xml file

then it's all good
ENJOY.......

Answer (score 0):

If does not matter, you can use ActionBarSherlock, this example from demos:
[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]
[image: Landscape expand]

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider;

/**
 * This activity demonstrates how to use an {@link android.view.ActionProvider}
 * for adding functionality to the Action Bar. In particular this demo is adding
 * a menu item with ShareActionProvider as its action provider. The
 * ShareActionProvider is responsible for managing the UI for sharing actions.
 */
public class ShareActionProviders extends SherlockActivity {

    private static final String SHARED_FILE_NAME = "shared.png";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(R.string.share_action_providers_content);
        copyPrivateRawResuorceToPubliclyAccessibleFile();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate your menu.
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_action_provider, menu);

        // Set file with share history to the provider and set the share intent.
        MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar);
        ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
        actionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
        // Note that you can set/change the intent any time,
        // say when the user has selected an image.
        actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

        //XXX: For now, ShareActionProviders must be displayed on the action bar
        // Set file with share history to the provider and set the share intent.
        //MenuItem overflowItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_overflow);
        //ShareActionProvider overflowProvider =
        //    (ShareActionProvider) overflowItem.getActionProvider();
        //overflowProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(
        //    ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
        // Note that you can set/change the intent any time,
        // say when the user has selected an image.
        //overflowProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a sharing {@link Intent}.
     *
     * @return The sharing intent.
     */
    private Intent createShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath("shared.png"));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        return shareIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Copies a private raw resource content to a publicly readable
     * file such that the latter can be shared with other applications.
     */
    private void copyPrivateRawResuorceToPubliclyAccessibleFile() {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.robot);
            outputStream = openFileOutput(SHARED_FILE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            try {
                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                /* ignore */
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            /* ignore */
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
               /* ignore */
            }
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
               /* ignore */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ShareActionProviders.java

Comment: Wrong. If you use a split action bar with that demo (`android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`) it exhibits exactly the same problem on pre-ICS with ActionBarSherlock as it does with the native implementation.