# Android Action Bar actions not showing all options, or in middle of UI, and other problems

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I cannot get my action bar to work right at all.  There's way too many crazy examples to run through, but I have encountered things like the action bar overflow bottom showing up halfway down the UI in 4.0.3 (I'm using android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"), to clicking item A yet item B showing as the selecting item in OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem), or not showing them all.

Not trying to do anything crazy.  I just want a refresh icon, info icon, share icon to show up and then 2 extra options to show up from clicking the dotted overflow icon.  But I cannot get it to work consistently.  I need to support 4.0+.

Here's what I have right now.  I have slaughtered the menu xml while pulling my hair out, but maybe someone can shed some light on what I must be doing horribly wrong?
This current xml causes the bottom split action bar to sit right in the middle for the 4.0.3 AVD:

```
 <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:title="@string/action_refresh"
      android:showAsAction="always" /> 

 <item android:id="@+id/action_info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
        android:title="@string/action_info"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

 <item
     android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     android:title="@string/action_share"
     android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_category"  
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_category" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_about"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the share action provider was cause of most the issues.  Just using an icon with click handler that builds a share Intent instead.
[Similar issue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162521/shareactionprovider-with-a-split-actionbar)